# How can I run a VBScript in Wix before Installation begins?

Tags: vbscript, wix, custom-action

This code works:

```
    <CustomAction Id="StopVBS" Directory="INSTALLDIR" ExeCommand="wscript.exe stop.vbs" Execute="immediate" Return="ignore" />
```

This is the problem, because the script is not located in the INSTALLDIR:

```
<Binary Id="StopAll" SourceFile="source\stop-all.vbs" />
<CustomAction Id="StopAllVBS" BinaryKey="StopAll" ExeCommand="wscript.exe stop-all.vbs" Execute="immediate" Return="ignore">
</CustomAction>
<InstallUISequence>
<Custom Action="StopAllVBS" After="CostFinalize" />
</InstallUISequence>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: you can use <Custom Action="StopAllVBS" Before="InstallInitialize" /> if the file is already in the dir before the installation begin  , or <Custom Action="StopAllVBS" After="InstallInitialize" /> if the msi installs the file

Comment: the file (stop-all.vbs) is not yet in the INSTALLDIR, but the job has to run after COSTFINALIZE, because the installation works only correct, if the VBS-Script run before (script is stopping some processes). My problem is, how can I tell Wix the location of the script???

Comment: you can add browse button  and navigate to the file location then store it in a property, or send the location from your bootstrapper to the msi and store it in property

Comment: Thanks and sorry, I am not very experienced in Wix. Do you have an example?

Comment: when your executing your wix msi from cmd , you can set the properties values. For example Create new process and set the arguments : msiexec /i \"{0}\\{6}.msi\" PATHNAME=\"{0}\" SSLCERTPATH=\"{1}\"" +
                        " MSINEWINSTANCE=1 TRANSFORMS=\":{2}\" USERPATH={3} ENVIRONMENTPATH={4} SSLCERTPASS=\"{5}\" /L*v \"{0}\\{6}Log.txt\""
                        , XmlSettings.EnvironmentFolderPath, FindCertificates.SslCertPath, environment, XmlSettings.IisUserFolderPath,
                        XmlSettings.EnvironmentFolderPath, FindCertificates.SslCertPass, msiName)

Comment: In your msi file for example the USERPATH property will be set to the value u provided in the cmd

Comment: is it possible to copy the script in the local TempFolder before Installation starts?